# cannot name connection in qt

Tags: c++, qt

```
QSqlDatabase db;
DBCONNECTION( QString conName)
{
    db.addDatabase("QMYSQL",conName);
    db.setDatabaseName("mitsubishi");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("");
    qDebug()<<db.connectionName()<<conName;

}
```

db.connectionName returns empty string
but conName returns "string"
whats the problem?
and while executing query driver is not loaded

Answer (score 2):

[`QSqlDatabase::addDatabase`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase) is a static function which returns a `QSqlDatabase` object. So it is not doing anything to your existing `QSqlDatabase` object. How you should use it:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", conName);
```